# Why does "dd" in a python subprocess write no bytes to STDOUT?

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, dd

I want to redirect the output of a "dd" command to stdout in my python script. This is my code:

```
def dd2pipe():
    chunk=654321
    skip_ntimes= 2
    read_ntimes= 3
    filepath='39476a90-a5f1-cd59-7a8d-34c016276514.high.mp3' 

    p1_cmds = [f'dd bs={chunk}', 
               f'skip={skip_ntimes}', 
               f'count={read_ntimes}', 
               f'if={filepath}']

    p1 = sp.Popen(p1_cmds,shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.STDOUT)
    byte_data= p1.stdout.read()
    p1.stdout.close()
    p1.wait()
    print(byte_data)

dd2pipe()
```

the output I get is:

```
b'0+0 records in\n0+0 records out\n0 bytes copied, 2,338e-05 s, 0,0 kB/s\n'
```

Can you help me to read the bytes of the dd command in STDOUT?

Comment: Notice how `dd` and `bs={chunk}` are in the same array element, but the other arguments aren’t. You should change that to be consistent in one direction or the other and pick `shell=True` or `shell=False` accordingly.

Comment: What happens when you manually do that same `dd` command outside of a Python script? Directly on the command line?

Comment: Why are you using `dd` anyway? Just read the bytes with Python.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Using `dd` is probably more concise (and possibly more efficient) than reimplementing its functionality in Python. If you think of it as a DSL, I think the benefits outweigh the costs of starting a new process.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ry-s answer it works. I changed shell to False and p1_cmds to:

```
p1_cmds = ['dd',                 
           f'bs={chunk}', 
           f'skip={skip_ntimes}', 
           f'count={read_ntimes}', 
           f'if={filepath}']

p1 = sp.Popen(p1_cmds,shell=False, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.STDOUT)
```

Comment: `shell=False` is the default; you can omit the keyword argument altogether.

Comment: Also, note that this is *one* command, with arguments, not multiple commands.